# Unable to restore a SQL Server 2008 database from multiple bak files using SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-restore

I am trying to restore a `SQL SERVER 2008` database from multiple `.bak` files using SSMS, but I am getting the following error:

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: File
>   'D:\SQL2008_R2L1\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008_R2L1\MSSQL\DATA\KCNA_RELEASE.mdf'
>   is claimed by 'promax_data02'(4) and 'promax_data01'(1). The WITH MOVE
>   clause can be used to relocate one or more files.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)"

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure to enter a valid and **unique** db name in the Restore to: box
2. make sure to use **unique** file names for Data and Log files in the "Restore As" boxes (including being valid windows file names) and that they have the proper .mdf,.ndf,.ldf extensions.